# Do all cumulative distributions have the property that it is equal to 1 outisde of the domain?

Tags: probability-distributions

Relearning cumulative distribution functions and their definitions, it says that $F_x$ is a CDF if it is non-decreasing and right continuous with value of $1$ for large $x$ and value of $0$ for negatively large $x$.

But this just says that it can increase to $1$, not that outside its domain, it is $1$.
Might be confusing if I don't give a function:
I'll give a PDF:

$f(x) = 2nx^{2n-1}$ for $0<x<1$.

How would I find the cumulative distribution function? I'd integrate it but is this correct?

$$F(X) = \begin{cases} x^{2n} \quad 0<x<1 \\ 1 \quad \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Logic tells me that it has to be $1$ (otherwise) because I want the integral from $0$ to $a$ where $a>1$ to be equal to 1?

A question that I'm stuck on that's related to this: How would I show a random variable with this distribution converges in probability to 1? I know the definition but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.
The cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$ is defined to be the function $F$ such that
$$ F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X\le x). $$
Let $x \to -\infty$, do you think that $\lim_{x \to - \infty} F(x) = 1$ (your claim implies so)? 
On the other hand, $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F(x) = 1$ since it is $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \mathbb{P}(X\le x) = \mathbb{P}(X\le +\infty) = 1$.

In particular, one can prove that the cumulative distribution function has the following properties:

- $F$ is non-decreasing, right-continuous,
- $\lim_{x\to - \infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to + \infty} F(x) = 1$.

For a proof, see, e.g., Proposition 3.9 of I. Florescu and C.A. Tudor's book [Handbook of Probability](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470647272.html) or Theorem 7.2 of J. Jacod and P. Protter's book [*Probability Essentials*](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9783540438717).

---

EDIT (i.e., tentative of answer to the second question)

Let $\{X_n\}$ be the sequence of random variables with cumulative distribution function given by the one you have in the exercise, i.e.,
$$ F_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } x \le 0, \\ x^{2n}, & \text{if } 0<x<1, \\ 1, & \text{if } x \ge 1. \end{cases} $$

Notice $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} F_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } x < 1, \\ 1, & \text{if } x \ge 1, \end{cases} $$
that is, $X_n$ converges in distribution to $1$ (i.e., a *constant*).
What can you conclude?

Comment: Thanks!  

I see now, it converges in distribution (to a constant) to it must converge in probability (because it's a constant)?

Comment: Another related question: If we had a PDF, such that its endpoint was the same $(0,1)$, except the PDF's maximum value is (say) $2$ (i.e. $f(1) = 2$), would it be safe to say that for $x\geq 1$, the CDF is defined to be $2$ instead of $1$ that we have in the example I first gave?  
I ask this because it seems the CDF is defined to be $1$ only because $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: It converges in probability to $1$ because it converges in distribution to $1$, that is a constant. Notice that if it does not converge in distribution to a constant but to some other random variable, then you can not conclude that it converges in probability. Answer to the second question: in this case, $F(1) = \int_{-\infty}^1 f(x) \, dx = 1$, hence $F$ has to be $1$ for $x \ge 1$ since $F$ is non-decreasing and always less than 1 (def. of probability measure).

Comment: Thank you! I meant if there was a PDF such that $F(2) = 1 = \int_{-\infty}^{2} f(x)dx$ then can we conclude that $F(a)$ for $a\geq 2$ is equal to $2$ (since right continuous)? I didn't know that $F$ had to be less than 1

Comment: It has to be less than $1$ since $F(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \le x)$ and, by definition, $\mathbb{P} \colon \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks, cleared all my confusions! :D